# Adjusting height of a Custom layout in a dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog with custom layout, everything is working fine, except there is a big empty spaces at the bottom which i cannot remove.

Any suggestion how i can remove that empty space.

Here is my Code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue_cover_staying, null))

    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   //action
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   finish();
               }
           });      

   return builder.show();  
}
```

My XML Layout:

```
  ` 
     <LinearLayout

     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/back1"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView

     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.00"
     android:background="@drawable/box"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:text="Enter Covers and Guest Type"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <EditText

    android:id="@+id/et_covers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="Covers"
    android:inputType="number" />

   <TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="Staying Guest...?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="YES" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:text="NO" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout> `
```

[image: Custom AlertDialog box]

Comment: Did u forget to add the closing tag for the root linear layout?

Comment: your back1.png image has that height

Comment: Sorry i forgot about back1.png 's height.. Now its all fixed. Thanks boss.

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout width and height from "wrap_content" to "100dp" for example..like this..

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:background="@drawable/back1"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Moreover you can set minWidth and minHeight..

```
 android:minWidth="300dp" 
 android:minHeight="400dp"
```